# Connect to Oracle database as apex_version user

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-18c

I'm talking about schemas like `APEX_040200`, `APEX_050100`, `APEX_180300`, `APEX_190100` etc.

I'm trying to install an APEX Plug-in that is being installed from a script, where developper commented `Assumes you are running the script connected to SQL*Plus as the Oracle user APEX_040200 or as the owner (parsing schema) of the application`. I have APEX 19 installed, so it's `APEX_190100` then.

Empty password didn't do the trick, default password I don't know. Is there a way to change it's password harmlessly? Or are there any ways to install this plugin to the whole APEX instaince, not only to a certain workspace?

Comment: Link to Plug-in? "Parsing schema" <> "owner of application".  Never install anything in `APEX_*version*`

Comment: @MichaelKutz Select2

Comment: @MichaelKutz How can I find out my parsing schema or app owner? For example, owner of a workspace is `SCH_WS01` schema. Is it what I need?

Comment: Are you in installing in a "runtime only" environment?  Where did you get the plugin? Http://apex.world or somewhere else? The one on apex.world looks like a standard plugin that you can import.